# Using leaflet.js, how do I iterate through markers in a cluster?

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

Se we have a map and at a certain zoom level we start clustering the markers.

Now I want to be able to delete certain markers.  I can delete the markers that don't participate in a cluster but the markers in a cluster do not get deleted because the code doesn't iterate through them.

I'd post code but it's all over the place and quite specific.

I can do the following;

```
$.each(MAP._layers, function (i, layer) {
    if (layer.feature) {
        var marker = LIGHTWEIGHT_BUILDING_MAPPING[layer.feature.id];
        MAP.removeLayer(marker);
    }
});
```

And all the visible markers are removed but not the ones within a cluster.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't iterate though markers in a map or a cluster.

Create an array where you push the markers when you create them.

Iterate through your array

When you have to remove a marker, use

```
if(cluster.hasLayer(marker) cluster.removeLayer(marker);
if(map.hasLayer(marker) map.removeLayer(marker);
// remove marker from array (easier with a jQuery Array)
```